# Display the flood zone near Elicott City MD

Tags: curated-data, geographics

Ellicott City, Maryland was the site of a serious flash flood several years ago, due to the local topography. How can we use the Wolfram Language to make a graphic that shows the area at risk of flooding? It might help to find the lowest elevation near Ellicott City, and use `ResourceFunction["GeoElevationGraphics3D"]`.

Comment: I tried `ResourceFunction["GeoElevationGraphics3D"][Entity["City", {"EllicottCity", "Maryland", "UnitedStates"}]]` in the cloud but unfortunately it ran out of memory for my plan. Could that be a starting point though?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Locate the center and fix the range of the shown map:

```
center = Entity["City", {"EllicottCity", "Maryland", "UnitedStates"}];
range = Quantity[4, "Miles"];
```

Get an idea of where we are:

```
GeoGraphics[GeoCenter -> center, GeoRange -> range]
```

[image]

Download the elevation data:

```
data = GeoElevationData[center, GeoRange -> range,
         GeoProjection -> Automatic, UnitSystem -> "Imperial"];
{mi, ma} = QuantityMagnitude[MinMax[data]]
(*    {80.2862, 605.287}    *)
```

Draw a relief map with a "flood level" manipulator:

```
Manipulate[ReliefPlot[data, DataReversed -> True, PlotRange -> {level, ma}],
           {level, mi, ma}]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh how nice ($+1$).

Comment: It does look like a very unfortunate place to build a city: `ReliefPlot[GeoElevationData[GeoCenter -> GeoPosition[{39.26777632053404, -76.7941653003265}], GeoRange -> Quantity[1, "Miles"], GeoProjection -> Automatic, UnitSystem -> "Imperial"], DataReversed -> True, PlotRange -> {180, 500}]`