# Map water runoff flows near Ellicott City, Maryland

Tags: visualization, vector-calculus, geographics

Ellicott City, Maryland was the site of a flash flood several years ago due to the local topography. How can we use the Wolfram Language to show the direction water flows at many points near that city? A good start is code by Roman from the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284956/display-the-flood-zone-near-elicott-city-md):

```
center = Entity["City", {"EllicottCity", "Maryland", "UnitedStates"}];
range = Quantity[4, "Miles"];
elevationData = 
  GeoElevationData[
    center, GeoRange -> range, 
    GeoProjection -> Automatic, UnitSystem -> "Imperial"
  ];
```

I envision using [ListVectorPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListVectorPlot.html) to show many vectors that are perpendicular to the equal elevation contours (all pointing downhill). The hard part is making the array of vectors from elevationData.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just an idea by smoothing the elevation data with `MeanFilter` and using `grad` function from [@xzczd's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/250412/75628):

```
grad[mat_] := grad[mat, ##] & @@ ConstantArray[1, Length@Dimensions@mat]
grad[mat_, dx__] := 
  1/{dx} (NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[#, 
       Range@N@Dimensions@mat, mat, DifferenceOrder -> 2] & /@ 
     IdentityMatrix@Length@{dx});

(* Change to control the smoothness *)
smoothingRadius = 16;

elevationDataSmooth = 
  MeanFilter[QuantityMagnitude@elevationData, {smoothingRadius, smoothingRadius}];

vec = Map[{#[[1]], -#[[2]]} &, 
   Reverse[Transpose[-grad[elevationDataSmooth, 100, 100], {3, 2, 1}], 
    {2, 3}], {-2}];

Show[ReliefPlot[elevationData, DataReversed -> True, 
  ColorFunction -> (Opacity[.5, ColorData["GreenBrownTerrain"][#]] &)], 
 ListStreamPlot[vec, StreamPoints -> Fine]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could try to fit an interpolation function and then take the negative Gradient of it.

First we must get rid of the unit:

```
dat=QuantityMagnitude[elevationData];
```

Then we get an interpolation function:

```
inter = ListInterpolation[dat]
```

Now we can take the Gradient:

```
grad = Grad[inter[x, y], {x, y}]
```

Then we can plot the gradients:

```
vecplot = VectorPlot[grad, {x, 1, 438}, {y, 1, 436}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

and make a contour plot of the landscape:

```
cp = ContourPlot[inter[x, y], {x, 1, 438}, {y, 1, 436}, 
  ColorFunction -> (White &)]
```

[image]

Finally we plot both together:

```
Show[cp, vecplot]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]